# How to change the color of radiobuttons dynamically?

Tags: android

I am trying to build MCQ Quiz in an Android app.
I have already dislayed the question and now i want to check if the answers are correct.There are 5 questions and there is a submit button at last, once a user selects all the answer and presses 'submit' i want to change the color of the radio buttons.
If answer is correct the button should be green but if answer is wrong the button should be red and correct answer should be made green.

Comment: I'm voting to off-topic **questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If your target api is >21 use the following attribute in your check to change the color programmaticaly:

```
yourRadioButton.setBackgroundTintList(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.yourcolor));
```

otherwise set your buttons as

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton />
```

and use the following:

```
yourRadioButton.setSupportButtonTintList(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.yourcolor));
```

Edit: I should clarify that your color should be a [Color State List Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource). Here's the syntax of a generic template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:color="hex_color"
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```